# Getting the Error message when I tried to update multiple column in oracle 11 g

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I am new to Oracle 11g SQL command line.
I am trying to update multiple columns with the one query.

I ran this command to update User_information table.

```
update user_information 
   set email = 'new@email.com', set name = 'new_name' 
where username = 'ajau';
```

> error :ORA -017747 invalid user.table.column ,table.column or column

specification

[screen shot from SQL command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujcOa.png)

nb: all column is varchar type.

when i run below command

`update user_information set email = 'new@email.com'  where username = 'ajau';`

email is updated

[Sceen shot when the only email is updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hovn.png)

let me know if required more information
thank for help

Comment: Specify SET keyword only once.

Comment: More details here: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_10008.htm

Answer (score 3):

You are including the SET keyword twice, you only specify it once

```
update user_information set 
email = 'new@email.com' 
, name = 'new_name' 
where username = 'ajau';
```

Comment: Silly mistake,

thanks Andrew , it worked